# Storybook - Cannot find module in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm, storybook

I have a Vue component that I'm importing into my StoryBook story. If I run `storybook build` or `storybook dev` it works as expected, however WebStorm is highlighting the import as not found.
If I remove the import and auto-import it using WebStorm, it adds this exact import too. The import is correct.

It also doesn't work if the Vue file is directly next to the story file.

[image: Cannot find module]

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

**vite.config.ts**

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import {resolve} from 'path'
import {fileURLToPath} from "url";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts"

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue(),  dts({
        insertTypesEntry: true,
    })],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    build: {

        lib: {
            // src/indext.ts is where we have exported the component(s)
            entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/main.ts"),
            name: "ComponentsLibrary",
            // the name of the output files when the build is run
            fileName: "components-library",
        },

        rollupOptions: {
            // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
            // into your library
            external: ["vue"],
            output: {
                // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build
                // for externalized deps
                globals: {
                    vue: "Vue",
                },
            },
        },
    },

})
```

**.storybook/main.ts**

```
import type {StorybookConfig} from "@storybook/vue3-vite";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
    stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
    addons: [
        "@storybook/addon-links",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials",
        "@storybook/addon-interactions",
        "@storybook/preset-typescript",
        "@storybook/preset-vue",
        "storybook-addon-vue-slots"
    ],
    framework: {
        name: "@storybook/vue3-vite",
        options: {},
    },
    docs: {
        autodocs: "tag",
    },
};
export default config;
```

**Directory Structure**

[image: Directory Structure]

What could be causing this? Is it a bug in WebStorm?

Here is the complete project.

https://github.com/Michael2109/component-library